# Very basic question on subfields of $x^3-2$

Tags: galois-theory

I am quite confused here, 
I know that that there are four subfields of the splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb Q$ . 
But since $\mathbb Q (\omega) = \mathbb Q(\omega^2)$ i am failing to see why $\mathbb Q(\omega \sqrt[3]2)$ and $\mathbb Q(\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2})$ are different ?

thanks !

Comment: A comma of difference changes it all ! Do not mistake $\mathbb Q(\omega \sqrt[3]2)$ for $\mathbb Q(\omega,\sqrt[3]{2})$ (the first field is stricty included in the second).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if $L = \mathbb Q(\omega \sqrt[3]{2}) = \mathbb Q(\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2})$, then $\omega = \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2} (\omega \sqrt[3]{2})^{-1}\in L$, so that $L = E$, where $E = \mathbb Q(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})$ is the splitting field. But $\lvert E : \mathbf{Q} \rvert = 6 \ne 3 = \lvert L : \mathbf{Q} \rvert $.